# Polygon into shader

Tags: opengl, shader, polygon

I'm writing a game. Now there is rendering of the water. I have a polygon:
[image]

All the scene is rendered into a single texture and when the water's queue comes I want to pass a complex polygon into the shader. For example, at screen the polygon is red water surface and blue borders. How to pass into shader only the area inside of that polygon? For example, I want to fill everything inside polygon into red color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you’re doing with it, it might be better to render the polygon into a texture by itself and have your shader sample that. If the polygon’s going to be a predictable size, you could use a texture with roughly those dimensions and pass that frame’s position in your scene into the shader too.

Comment: So, the idea is to fill the polygin with a color, pass that texture into shader. All area would be transparent except the part with filled polygon. And in shader I just need to check that current pixel isn't transparent. That's it?

Comment: That could work. You probably want the texture to be black-and-white (or grayscale), just for memory’s sake. You might also want to look into stenciling to easily get the intersection of your “water” shape with your… whatever’s-floating-in-the-water shape.